# How do I send large POST data with ajax in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, jquery, post, get

I get the following error when using the function below:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Large).

The function works fine when data is not too long, the problem is, in some cases, rez and com get lengthy and ajax seems to be using GET, not POST.
Can anyone explain to me why ajax is using GET when I declared POST? And how may I prevent that? Thank you.

```
jQuery('#buton_submit').click(function() {
    var rez = {};
    var com = {};
    jQuery("input[name^='sb-rez']:checked").each(function() {
        rez[jQuery(this).attr('name').substr(7)] = jQuery(this).val();
    });
    jQuery("textarea[name^='sb-com']").each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
            com[jQuery(this).attr('name').substr(7)] = jQuery(this).val();
        }
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data:{
            'action':'admin_event',
            'fn':'saveResultsEvent',
            'method': 'POST',
            'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'processData': false,
            'r': rez,
            'c': com,
            'pid': jQuery('div[id="content"] :first-child').attr('id').substr(5)
        },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').html(data);
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').show('fast');
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').delay(3000).hide(1000);
        },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert('Error printed in console.');
        console.log(errorThrown); 
        }
    });
});
```

Correct .ajax call, for future reference (tryed to post it as answer, but I can't answer my own question for another 8 hours, due to lack of reputation):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    processData: false,
    data:{
        'action':'admin_event',
        'fn':'saveResultsEvent',
        'r': rez,
        'c': com,
        'pid': jQuery('div[id="content"] :first-child').attr('id').substr(5)
    },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').html(data);
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').show('fast');
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').delay(3000).hide(1000);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert('Error printed in console.');
        console.log(errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

The problem was I was wrongly declaring the type/method and the contentType in the data array, instead of as parameters of the ajax call and by default the method is GET.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo - look at the documentation for `jQuery.ajax()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and you will see that you define the method used with the `type` key, and not `method`. So your request should look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data:{
        'action':'admin_event',
        'fn':'saveResultsEvent',
        'type': 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
        'processData': false,
        'r': rez,
        'c': com,
        'pid': jQuery('div[id="content"] :first-child').attr('id').substr(5)
    },
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').html(data);
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').show('fast');
        jQuery('#arata_mesaje').delay(3000).hide(1000);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert('Error printed in console.');
        console.log(errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You were partially right. I don't remember where I got the example from, but I didn't question it, since it was working. I need to declare the type, contentType and processData outside of data, not in it.
Thank you for the quick reply. Was helpful.

Comment: Can you post your final `.ajax` call that worked and accept that as the correct answer in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: I posted as later edit. Tryed to post it as comment but was too long. Do I need to do otherwise?

Comment: Oh, well since you can't answer right away - just answer it after those 8 hours(if you remember to do so :) ) and accept it :)